# Missing options in carpenter's workbench

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

So I have a PS3 and all the DLC's (downloadable content) one of which is Hearthfire. So, I have since made, completed and moved in my family (husband, kids) into my first finished house.

I've been feeling pretty cluttered and like I needed more room so I decided to go see if it was possible to buy another house for storage purposes, so I go to the Jarl in Dawnstar.

To get this plot of land I had to kill a giant, which I did. I returned to the Jarl and I got my land to build on. I go to the location, all happy to begin building, no big deal. Right? WRONG!

So originally back at my house (1st one) if I went to my drafting table I had options to remove the carpenter's workbenches (which I have yet to do) or "remodel home into entryway" which I was absolutely not going to do to my first finished house, but the point is, at my new home, home #2, I had those options pop up in the misc section on my drafting table. It didn't bring up the house section where I can lay down the "small house layout". Only once I built an outside grindstone (because I was testing to see if it would help, or something) did the option to build the layout pop up. That was great and perfect, onto the foundation and frames, right?

Well, not exactly in my case, when I went to the carpenter's workbench right beside the drafting table to build for my house, no option popped up in the "house" section. Just the "misc" items, like the grindstone and the weapon and armory upgrade bench and stone wheel. I had no option to build my foundation.

Also, I had plenty of the materials needed (lumber, iron ingots, fittings, nails, etc.) to build these things. I had waited on the game, gone back to the carpenter's workbench several times, gone from one random place and back to see if that would do the trick, but no...

I'm feeling really at a loss, cause I spent money on this land (for presumably nothing ), and I just wanted a place for storage and to look out over the land in a library tower which I lack from my first home.

Overall, I want to now if there's a way to get these house building options to pop up, and start building.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a bug. I would reload a save from before buying the second plot of land and start over.