# Can't finish building my house

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

I started building a house in Skyrim and I got most of it done but it won't let me build the rest. When I go to the Carpenter's Workbench it is just a menu with nothing on it.

Comment: What isn't done about it? You build interior decorations at workbenches indoors. The workbench outdoors is for building the main hall and the wings of the house. Were you able to build all three wings?

Comment: @armadillo There's no opitions in the carpenter's workbench outside of the house

Comment: Look at the drafting table and see if you can select a new wing to build.

Comment: @armadillo I tryed that there's still no options

Comment: So the drafting table and the carpenter's workbench both have no options? That's not good...

Comment: You should be able to choose something in the drafting table, and then build it at the workbench. If the drafting table has no options, something has gone wrong.

Comment: @armadillo The only options in the drafting tables are to remove the workbenches in the house

Comment: So what isn't finished? Your house can have three wings, and you can remodel the starter house into an entryway. I think you build the stable and garden and stuff outside too. After that, I think you're done.

Comment: Are you using any mods? Can you upload screenshot of your house, workbench and drafting table options ?

Comment: @armadillo Well the thing is after that glitch with the carpenters workbench happened I was working on the west wing and I hadn't worked on ethier wings yet

Comment: I'd be tempted to back up to an older save file... I need to log off now, but maybe Paul or somebody can help.

Comment: @Paul No I'm on ps3

Comment: @armadillo Ok I think I'll reload a save file thabk you

Comment: Related: [Missing options in carpenter's workbench](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/202089/4797)

Answer (score 4):

It seems like this is a bug. [The UESP writes about a possible fix:](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Construction#Bugs)

> - The menu for the exterior carpenter's workbench may be blank, even if there are items available.
>
>   - Exiting the menu and selecting the workbench again may fix this. If the problem persists, try this fix multiple times.
> - The carpenter's workbenches may have items that you already have built listed as being available.
>
>   - Exiting the menu and selecting the workbench again may fix this. If the problem persists, try this fix multiple times.

Comment: Thats not working but I'll keep trying

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had mixed success across playthroughs, platforms, and rooms. Sometimes re-entering the menu is only necessary once; sometimes the correct menu will not appear even after re-entering several times. (The storage room seems to have a real problem with this on my current PC playthrough.) Usually, building an existing item (and losing those resources) will cause the correct, smaller menu to appear.

Comment: "Try turning it off and on again until it works" - Besthesda Support is great.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this bug on most of my playthroughs. A lot of time I'll build the foundation, then notice the option to build subsequent parts of the base house disappear.

What I normally do to fix it:

- Make sure there isn't an animal/npc on the building plot. A lot of
  times butterflies/rabbits are the culprit. If it's trapped under the
  foundation, sometimes a Fus-Ro-Dah can clear it.
- Sometimes leaving the work bench and running onto the foundation,
  then back to the work bench fixes it for me. I'm unsure if the object
  moves by the time I get to the foundation, or if there is a mod that 
  isn't rendering/updating items outside of the players view and this action causes it to update. I've found this method more reliable than
  constantly exiting and re-entering the menu.
- If all else fails, fast traveling to another location, waiting an extended period of time (48hrs?), and fast traveling back seems to fix it (7/8 times for my game).

Comment: A full reset of the area takes, at most, 30 days. Go to a far away place and sleep for 30 days straight, and this resets everything.

Answer (score -1):

If you remove and re-add the workbenches you should get the option to add anything that’s missing or glitched.

Comment: REMOVE and READD? How would they even correctly add the correct type of workbench and attach the right scripts to it? What are the console commands to do that?